# Web scraping data for use in R-Studio

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am wanting to pull the data out of this server site and into R-Studio. I am new to R so not at all sure what is possible. Any help with coding to achieve this would be appreciated.

http://hbrcdata.hbrc.govt.nz/hydrotel/cgi-bin/hydwebserver.cgi/points/details?point=679&samples=true

Comment: Cant you just copy paste the data to a excel sheet and then read it into R?

Comment: rvest is a popular package for web scraping in R. However, the table you want to scrape is in an iframe here, so I don't think rvest will work on its own. You might need to use rvest along with splashr or rselenium.

Comment: MLEN - when copied the data comes out as one line of text and the screen only shows about 10 days of data at a time. As I need years of data I am wanting to try and web scrape the actual data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.packages("rvest")
library('rvest')
install.packages('XML')
library('XML')
library("httr")


#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- 'http://hbrcdata.hbrc.govt.nz/hydrotel/cgi- 
        bin/hydwebserver.cgi/points/samples?point=679'





webpage <- read_html(url)

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

head(tbls)


tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
           html_nodes("table") %>%
           html_table(fill = TRUE)

tbl <- as.data.frame(tbls_ls)

View(tbl)
```

I have tried to fetch few other tables from the given website which is working fine.

for example:

rainfall depth:

```
http://hbrcdata.hbrc.govt.nz/hydrotel/cgi-bin/hydwebserver.cgi/points/details?point=63
```

small modification in the url as follows will fetch you actual table. rest all code reamins same (**details?point=63** as **samples?point=63**)

```
url <- 'http://hbrcdata.hbrc.govt.nz/hydrotel/cgi-bin/HydWebServer.cgi/points/samples?point=63'
```

for more help you can refer the website:
http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/2015/12/scraping-html-tables.html

Comment: Thanks Anil Kumar, that worked really well for the default data that is showing in the table. What I am really trying to achieve is to scrape the data hiding behind that table/iframe.